# Special characters within indexed fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I facing some interesting behavior while searching email addresses with Query String Filter:

```
.filteredQuery(
   queryStringQuery(String.format("*%s*", query))
       .field("firstName").field("lastName").field("email").field("phone"),
   null
)
```

if I pass `domain.com` as a query (assuming there is such value in the index) - results are fine, but once I pass `@domain.com` - results are empty.. Are there some limitations for special symbols?

Comment: How does your mapping for the `email` field look like?

Comment: @Val string, by default

Answer (score 1):

If you set to true `analyze_wildcard` it should work. By default, query string doesn't analyze those tokens that contain wildcard. if you set that option to true elasticsearch will try. This option is not perfect as doc says:

> By setting this value to true, a best effort will be made to analyze those as well.

The reason behind your empty result is that the default analyzer is removing the `@` and when searching `*@domain.com*` and `analyze_wildcard` is false, the `@` is not being removed at query time.

Code will look like:

```
.filteredQuery(
    queryStringQuery(String.format("*%s*", query)).analyzeWildcard(true)
        .field("firstName").field("lastName").field("email").field("phone"),
    null
)
```

EDIT: Better explanation of why you get empty result.

First of all, analyzers can be executed at index(you set this in your mapping) time and at query time (not all query execute the analyzer at query time)

In your case, at index time `standard analyzer` is analyzing field `email` as follows:

`name@domain.com` => it's being indexed `name` and `domain.com`

This means that your document will contain two tokens `name` and `domain.com`. If you tried to find [exact term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) "name@domain.com" you wouldn't find anything because your document no longer contains the full email.

Now at query time you are doing a query string `*@domain.com*`. By default query string doesn't analyze those tokens that contain wildcards, so you are trying to find tokens that contain `@domain.com` that it not the case of your index.

Now if you set property `analyze_wildcard` to true. Elasticsearch analyzes those tokens with wildcard so your query would be transformed into `*domain.com*` and in this case you have documents that match.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am kind of confused.. You said that by default query string with wildcard is not analyzed, but after that you say that default analyzer removes the `@ ` which means that  query string tokes being yes analyzed.. Next, you say that when `analyze_wildcard` is false, then the `@` is not being removed and that's why results are empty.. If I understood you right,they empty because indexed field was analyzed and all the special characters were removed, right?

Comment: @nKognito I edited the answer with a better explanation. Hope it helps.